# Syntax errors in mysql with procedure, triggers and signal

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I feel embarrassed that I have to come and ask for help with this, but as surely many before me have learned, it seems mySQL syntax error messages are about as useful as a pope hat on a grizzly bear.  Attached is my first attempt at writing a trigger for a car company database.  The table, can_lease, relates the id of an employee and the id of a car model.  The trigger is expected to enforce two rules: 1) there can be at most 10 car models associated with 1 employee, and 2) the employee must be of type leasing (there is a column 'leasing' which must equal 'Y').

So the goal is for the trigger to catch violations of this rule and send a signal and a message explaining the violation.  I'm simply not sure what the errors are, but I will attach the relevant error messages as well.

```
create procedure can_lease_check (eid int)
begin
        declare can_lease_too_many_models condition for sqlstate '90001';
        if ((select count(rent_model_id) from can_lease where emp_id = eid) >= 10)
        then signal sqlstate '90001' set message_text = 'employee can lease at most 10 rent models.';

        declare can_lease_not_leaser for sqlstate '90002';                                                                                           
        if not (select leasing from employer where employer.emp_id = eid) == 'Y'                                                                     
        then signal sqlstate '90002' set message_text = 'employee must be of type "leasing"';
end;

delimiter $$
create trigger can_lease_insert_trigger
after insert on can_lease
for each row begin
    call can_lease_check(new.emp_id);
end;
$$

create trigger can_lease_update_trigger
after update on can_lease
for each row begin
    call can_lease_check(new.emp_id);
end;
$$
```

And here are the error messages:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if ((select count(rent_model_id) from can_lease where emp_id = eid) >= 10)
    then' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 1
```

Thank you for your help!  I would also appreciate any advice one has for debugging this sort of thing in general.  Coming from gcc telling me at least *something* about why my code is wrong, this is a very foreign process!

EDIT: I realize that I should have moved the delimiter change up to above the procedure as well.  I don't get it, but that removes all but one of the errors. Currently, the error is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (select count(rent_model_id) from can_lease where emp_id = eid) == 10
    then s' at line 4
```

Comment: I answered your original question not having noticed your edit. I will leave my answer in case it helps someone else. Also, regarding your second question, there seems to be difference between the error you posted in your edit (`where emp_id = eid) == 10 then s`) and the code in your original question (`where emp_id = eid) >= 10)`). Besides, did you end up figuring out the issue? If so, consider answering your own question here to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolons (`;`) between the first `begin` and `end` keywords are the culprits. Just enclose your original `create` block with a `DELIMITER`, as follows. I use `#` as the delimiter in my example, and I recognize that you use `$$`, though there will be no resulting difference.

```
DELIMITER #
create procedure can_lease_check (eid int)
begin
    declare can_lease_too_many_models condition for sqlstate '90001';
    if ((select count(rent_model_id) from can_lease where emp_id = eid) >= 10)
    then signal sqlstate '90001' set message_text = 'employee can lease at most 10 rent models.';

    declare can_lease_not_leaser for sqlstate '90002';                                                                                           
    if not (select leasing from employer where employer.emp_id = eid) == 'Y'                                                                     
    then signal sqlstate '90002' set message_text = 'employee must be of type "leasing"';
end#
```

Also, there will be no difference if you end it like I did (`end#`), or like you did, with the semicolon after the `end` keyword:

```
end;
#
```